# Spring-Drools integration?

Tags: spring, drools

There used to be spring-modules project that provides this integration; however, that project is deprecated now. Does anyone now if there is any continued support for this integration? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Work is in progress.
http://blog.athico.com/search?q=spring

Mark

Comment: Thanks for the information. In my case, I won't have any DRL source files, instead I have a guided editor (similar to that of Guvnor) to build the rule interactively and I'll store the compiled KnowledgePackage in database. So will this integration work for my use case?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can reference a .pkg as a resource. where the .pkg is just a serialised Package instance.